# Compute the coordinates of each corner of an image

Tags: vtk, dicom

How can I compute the coordinates of each corner of an image, by the renderer ?

Example:

```
double* pBounds = pImageData->GetBounds();
TRACE("%f.%f.%f.%f.%f.%f\n", pBounds[0], pBounds[1], pBounds[2], pBounds[3], pBounds[4], pBounds[5]);
```

Result:

```
-228.552734.0.000000.-228.552734.0.000000.0.000000.0.000000
```

Using vtkCoordinate ? But how ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I made it:

```
double* pBounds = pImageData->GetBounds();
vtkCoordinate* pCoordinate = vtkCoordinate::New();
pCoordinate->SetValue(0, 0, 0);
pCoordinate->SetValue(pBounds[0], pBounds[2], 0);
int* pValueInt = pCoordinate->GetComputedDisplayValue(m_pRenderer);
TRACE("BottomLeft:x:%d - y:%d\n", pValueInt[0], pValueInt[1]);
pCoordinate->SetValue(pBounds[1], pBounds[3], 0);
pValueInt = pCoordinate->GetComputedDisplayValue(m_pRenderer);
TRACE("TopRight:x:%d - y:%d\n", pValueInt[0], pValueInt[1]);
pCoordinate->SetValue(pBounds[2], pBounds[4], 0);
pValueInt = pCoordinate->GetComputedDisplayValue(m_pRenderer);
TRACE("TopLeft:x:%d - y:%d\n", pValueInt[0], pValueInt[1]);
pCoordinate->SetValue(pBounds[4], pBounds[2], 0);
pValueInt = pCoordinate->GetComputedDisplayValue(m_pRenderer);
TRACE("BottomRight:x:%d - y:%d\n", pValueInt[0], pValueInt[1]);
pCoordinate->Delete();
```

I wonder is if the right way to get image corners ...